# how to update an existing customer in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

when i run this code  a new row is inserted in the table.i want to update an existing customer in a row.

```
public function savepayment(Request $request,$amount)
{
    $title ='Save Payment';
    $payment = new Customer();
    $payment ->paid = 'yes';
    $payment->save();

    Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'Amount Paid Successfully'));

    return Redirect::action('Admin\CustomerController@paymentcustomer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function savepayment(Request $request,$amount)
{
    $title ='Save Payment';
    $payment = Customer::find('customer_id'); //need to find the customer before updating the existing customer
    $payment ->paid = 'yes';
    $payment->update(); //use update() instead of save()

    Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'Amount Paid Successfully'));

    return Redirect::action('Admin\CustomerController@paymentcustomer');
}
```

Comment: You have to find customer to update info of customer